# Find The Hidden Clue

Tags: riddle

What may I be?
I sometimes make you thirsty
Mostly I am peaceful
Nobody can order me
Sometimes I destroy things
Deadly I can sometimes be

### Edit

Hint:

> Midwesterners encounter it the most, not stopped by anything

Comment: There is no need to call people out in the title.  There isn't much need for a special request like that -- perhaps a **gentle** reminder, but that purpose is better served by a short note at the end of your puzzle or in the comments.

Comment: All right; I was a bit furious at a person who downvoted it and told me no reason why.

Comment: It's bound to happen, and will likely happen often. Rather than concentrating on the downvotes, focus on how you can get more upvotes.  If you're going to post more riddles, try improving your writing style. Reduce repeated words (e.g. "sometimes" 2x in 2 lines), include fuller phrasing (e.g. "Nobody can order me around"), rhymes are fun but don't sacrifice readability, and aim for a more consistent voice ("Mostly I am peaceful" is somewhat utilitarian, whereas "Deadly I can be" is more flowery language).

Comment: I downvoted because the riddle shows no ingenuity. The initial letter trick almost works, but there's an extra M thrown in there for seemingly no reason. I don't mean to offend, but it seems like there wasn't much thought put into this.

Comment: All right, well, consider this: In the final sceme, you are supposed to discard 2 lines that were added in as fillers (tricks) +Deusovi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could the answer be

> Wind

Because:

> Wind can keep rain away from places as well as in certain days de-moisturise someone (Sometimes make you thirsty); Gentle breezes abound everywhere (Mostly I am peaceful); unpredictable (Nobody can order me); wind in tornadoes and hurricanes wreck a lot of stuff and do kill people (Sometimes I destroy things / Deadly I can sometimes be)

And for the hint:

> Mid-west people "live on the prairie" where there are no natural obstructions (mountains, hills, and that stuff) to block the wind.

Also:

> I noticed that some of the letters that begin the lines can be rearranged to "WINDS"

Comment: Perfect! Just right! If you take away 2 of the paragraphs, it spells out what you said.

Comment: The sometimes I destroy things line was to mean "Destroy this line", meaning disregard it in the entire thing.

Comment: @TigerGold If the meaning of that line was to ignore it, why did you include it at all?

Answer (score 2):

Can it be

> the sea

I sometimes make you thirsty

> sea water doesn't quench your thirst. It increases if you drink it.

Mostly I am peaceful
Nobody can order me

> mostly peaceful and no one can order the sea

Sometimes I destroy things
Deadly I can sometimes be

> destroys sometimes.. tsunami, sea storms etc.

Comment: Not correct, but very clever!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from another answer that is now deleted I got this idea:

> Oil

Why does it also work?

- I sometimes make you thirsty

  > Stuff fried in oil would make you thirsty
- Mostly I am peaceful

  > Oil reservoirs don't really do much except sit underground
- Nobody can order me

  > You can't yell orders at oil, it will just sit there
- Sometimes I destroy things / Deadly I can sometimes be

  > Oil rig explosions as well as that that oil-based fires cause a lot of fires in vehicle crashes.